# swiftui forms not appearing inside list

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-form

I am developing a certain application where it requires a user to fill a form. a form is not a problem actually but problem is when i want more than just one form dynamically. The number of forms (of the same look) depends on a certain number. So i decided to create a model and put the form in the list. That way the number of forms will be equal to nth number. problem is they are not appearing. If i remove the form they appear, if i put a form they do not. Is it that a form is not allowed in the list?

Below is expected results

[image: This is what i want]

But when i add the form in the list i get
[image: This is what i get]

So here's my simple List:

```
struct UserTab: View {
let seats = ["A4", "B2", "C1", "D3"]
var body: some View {
    List(seats, id: \.self){seat in
        PassengerInfoModel()
    }
}
```

The PassengerInfoModel is below:

```
    struct PassengerInfoModel: View {
    @State private var fullName: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        Form{
            Text("Paasenger 1")
            TextField("Full name", text: $fullName)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will not achieve your expected result with Form, because it now have different look&feel (see for Form example iOS built-in Settings). You need custom view for your PassengerInfo (and probably in ScrollView instead of List, however it might depend). And, btw, Form is itself kind of List, so Form in List will behave weird. And, btw2, they are there, just scroll inside row.

Comment: I think i get your point. So to achieve the desired behaviour I can't get it with form. I have to create (fake a look) like form manually and use it instead. Im I correct?

Answer (score 11):

Because the form frame is not determined, you get this result.
Try to add some frame to your form and it should be ok

```swift
struct PassengerInfoModel: View {
    @State private var fullName: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        Form{
            Text("Paasenger 1")
            TextField("Full name", text: $fullName)
        }.frame(height: 200)
    }
}
```

**In general you should avoid using `Form` inside `Scrollview` because both of them has scroll and not working as you want**

Comment: Thanks for the answer and quick response, after I add the frame there is a weird behaviour. I can scroll one form while others are still (not moving) and not scrolling

Comment: It's because you are using the form inside scrollview and both of them have scroll behavior and the scroll is conflict. to avoid, you should use just one of these elements in your code

Comment: So... if i cant use form inside List because they both have scroll behaviour, and i cant use form alone with some sort of loop (scroll), How can i achieve that?

Comment: why do you need use form ? you can implement UI with scrollview and set your custom views in scrollview